# How to implement setDrawerLockMode or disable navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer activity with fragments within it by using a fragment container. I have three fragments within it and I need one of it named **locate_login** to not contain my navigation drawer.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); //nav drawer

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set the fragment initially
        locate_login fragment = new locate_login();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    public void onSelectFragment(View v){ //ignore this
        Fragment newFragment;

        if(v == findViewById(R.id.trigger)){
            newFragment = new locate_after();
        }
        else{
            newFragment = new locate_before();
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

}

}
```

**Here is my locate_login fragment**

```
public class locate_login extends Fragment{

    public locate_login () {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locate_login, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;

    }

}
```

I will highly appreciate it if the answer will be detailed since I'm a beginner on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for some constant parameter. Declare some constant variable like:

Let say `StringConstant.java` :

```
public static final int LOCK_DRAWER = 1;
public static final int SHOW_DRAWER = 2;
```

When navigating from the drawer, use an `Intent` object as:

If you want to show the drawer, use:

```
intent.putExtra("SHOW_DRAWER", StringConstant.SHOW_DRAWER);
```

OR

If you do not want to show the drawer, use:

```
intent.putExtra("SHOW_DRAWER", StringConstant.LOCK_DRAWER);
```

Retrieve intent from your `fragment` class, you say `locate_login`.

```
int status = getActivity.getIntent().getIntExtra("SHOW_DRAWER", 0);
```

Check status:

```
if (status == String.Constant.LOCK_DRAWER){
    lockDrawer();
}

public void lockDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}
```

To unlock the drawer:

```
public void unlockDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
}
```